# I can’t make my economy discord.py leaderboard work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this bot written in [Replit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replit) and discord.py and I can’t make the leaderboard work. I don't know why. I followed the [*Code With Swastik* tutorial *How to make a leaderboard in an economy Discord bot*, episode 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dI3_DWhfT8U).

I want to make a leaderboard which will show the top 5 people with the most money.

I use a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) file as the database (I know it’s not recommended, but I know how to use it so I use it).

JSON example for one person:

```
        "coins": 12253,
        "job": "none",
        "expirience": 0,
        "inventory": [],
        "bank": 10000
    }
```

The code for the leaderboard command:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['lb'])
async def leaderboard(ctx, pepol_to_show = 5):
  data = await get_bank_data()

  lb = {}
  total = []

  for user in data:
    name = int(user)
    total_amount = data[user]["coins"] + data[user]["bank"]
    lb[total_amount] = name
    total.append(total_amount)

  total = sorted(total,reverse=True)

  em4 = discord.Embed(title = f"Top {pepol_to_show} Richest people", description = "Who has the most potatoes (Wallet + Bank)", color = discord.Colour.red())
  index = 1
  for amt in total:
    id_ = lb[amt]
    member = bot.get_usser(id_)
    name = member.name
    em4.add_field(name = f"{index}. {name}", value = f"{amt}", inline = False)
    if index == pepol_to_show:
      break
    else:
      index += 1

  await ctx.reply(embed=em4)


async def get_bank_data():
  with open("users.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

  return data
```

When I run the *lb* command nothing is sent in [Discord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discord_(software)), and I get 0 errors. I don't have any idea why.

Why doesn’t this work? What do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have a typo, `member = bot.get_usser(id_)`, here. It should be just `get_user`. I tested it, and the code works fine otherwise.
2. You need to set up an error handler to see errors while sending commands with the [`on_command_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command_error#discord.discord.ext.commands.on_command_error) event

Or just a local error handler to see what's wrong:

```py
@leaderboard.error
async def leaderboard_error(ctx, error):
    print(error)
    print(type(error))
```

You can get the whole traceback after doing some work with the `traceback` module.

Comment: Hey it still doesnt work. Just changed the usser to user. Still no errors but 0 output in discord. I've set the on_command_error but only for cooldowns. How can i make my code work?

Comment: @NovaChr13 It s really hard to assume what s wrong when your code works fine on my end. 

I would suggest setting up error handler [docs example](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling) or [this gist](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/7822af90858ef65012ea500bcecf1612) for global erro hander. So let's probably use local error handler for now. I will edit answer